# The view orders.views.place_order didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and got this error. Can someboody please help me to figure out

Here is my views.py code

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
current_user = request.user



if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        data = Order()
        data.user = current_user
        data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
        data.save()
        return redirect('checkout)
else:
    return redirect('checkout')
```

Comment: If the form is not valid, your view does not return anything.

Comment: It also makes not much sense to redirect for a GET request. Usually you render the template with the form in case of a GET request, or in case the form is invalid, and you redirect when the POST request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is not valid in this case. But it still in the first if block.
But not entered into the 2nd if block. So, there is no, else block or  return to for that. Try to  Intend  return correctly may solve the problem. But still check your form. Its not valid.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        data = Order()
        data.user = current_user
        data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
        data.save()
    return redirect('checkout)
else:
    return redirect('checkout')
```